Can anyone identify this photo of Cairo in a music video?
At the start of the music video for Golden Brown - The Stranglers , the members of the band are shown inspecting a painting of the Nile as it runs through Cairo (the pyramids of Giza can also be seen).

Can anyone identify this painting as I am sure I have seen it in a museum?  I tried searching for it but couldn't find it.

This gallery of paintings by Charles Théodore Frère has some pretty similar ones but I don't see an exact match. Frère is also mentioned on The British Museum's page on Orientalism, but there are many other painters who did pyramids in this general style. If you could say which museum or country you saw it in with confidence, that would help, but I imagine you could just be remembering some similarly cliche image.

Hi Brian I found the painting I was thinking of but it was actually a different one like you said, there are countless similar paintings of the Nile and the pyramids of Giza.

So is this a "photo" or a "painting"? Why are you so sure you "have seen it in a museum"? Why couldn't it just have been a painting created for this video? It's utterly generic and similar to countless photos and paintings of the pyramids and the Nile.

Yes as indicated in the above comment I am aware there are many paintings like this and that I was remembering a different one.
